# Scrapy Splash missing elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I've written a spider to crawl the boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgame site for information regarding boardgames in the list.

My problem is that when pulling two specific selectors in my code, a response is not always received for those selectors, sometimes it returns a selector object other times it doesn't. After inspecting the response during debugging, the dynamically loaded selectors don't exist in the code.

My two offending lines

```
bggspider.py    

bg['txt_cnt'] = response.xpath(
        selector_paths.SEL_TXT_REVIEWS).extract_first()
    bg['vid_cnt'] = response.xpath(
        selector_paths.SEL_VID_REVIEWS).extract_first()
```

Where the selectors are defined as

```
selector_paths.py

SEL_TXT_REVIEWS = '//div[@class="panel-inline-
links"]/a[contains(text(), "All Text Reviews")]/text()'
SEL_VID_REVIEWS = '//div[@class="panel-inline-
links"]/a[contains(text(), "All Video Reviews")]/text()'
```

After yielding the bg item, in the pipeline the attributes are processed where a check is performed since many boardgames have very little information for various parts of the page.

```
pipelines.py

    if item['txt_cnt']:
        item['txt_cnt'] = int(re.findall('\d+', item['txt_cnt'])[0])
    else:
        item['txt_cnt'] = 0
    if item['vid_cnt']:
        item['vid_cnt'] = int(re.findall('\d+', item['vid_cnt'])[0])
    else:
        item['vid_cnt'] = 0
```

The aim of the field processing is just to grab the numerical value in the string which is the number of text and video reviews for a boardgame.

I'm assuming I'm missing something that has to do with Splash since I'm getting selector items for some/most queries but still missing many.
I am running the ScrapySplash docker container locally, localhost:8050.

Code for the spider can be found here. [BGGSpider on Github](https://github.com/nn-h/bggspider)

Any help or information about how to remedy this problem or how ScrapySplash works would be appreciated.

Comment: I think, that it's not a problem with Splash. Probably from page to page you have different HTML structure. Are you tried to make xpath query in a browser?

Comment: Yes I have, for example while scraping https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2651/power-grid the object returned a review count of 0, but when I inspect the page and query for the selectors I get an expected response.

Comment: I think I might have remedied this problem. I've increased the wait time for each SplashRequest to 2 seconds, although I wasn't getting bad response codes from my requests I think that my 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' setting in my settings.py for scrapy was not high enough so I've assigned a 5 second delay.

Comment: `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` probably will not help, better uses `wait` argument from Splash http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#arg-wait

Comment: Yeah, after reading docs, I saw it wouldn't help too much, added wait args to see if troubles disappear.

Comment: Comments/reviews might be loaded through ajax call. So you should use a lua script in this cases and add a wait for 5-10 seconds to get the code. Because a page may be loaded and returned to you without ajax call to be completed. Because splash will not have idea that a request is going to be initiated and for splash the page is loaded

Comment: I just want to add that I had the same issue (different site, ofc) and the ```DOWNLOAD_DELAY``` setting worked to resolve my problem.

I was previously using ```wait``` in conjunction with ```timeout``` in splash and neither resolved the problem.

I can't explain why DOWNLOAD_DELAY helped but it did.